# How can I see my hashrate for litecoin?

Tags: litecoin, synchronization, hashpower, miner-configuration, logging

Just for the sake of trying I installed Litecoin-Qt 0.6.3c on Ubuntu.
And for sure I started solo-mining.

The thing is, that the only thing I see is

```
[17:45:34] - Solo mining started
```

I am curious to find out with what speed am I mining, but looking into different tabs I have found no answer.

Is there a way to find my hashrate? Am I missing something?

Comment: Plz explain the reason to downvote

Comment: There're no explanations sometimes. But I think this is a good question.

Comment: The reason for the downvote is that some asshole is downvoting every question regarding any non-bitcoin currency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem.

The thing is that you can not start mining prior to synchronizing with the network (getting all the blocks). The client is not telling you this and tells you that it is mining, when in fact it does not.

So there is no point in clicking start mining before you got everything. After you got all the blocks and pressing mining you can see the your speed here.

[image]